# how to access global variable in other module?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm new to C, still struggling in understanding global variable,below is my code:

```
//test.c

int globalVariable = 2020;
```

```
//main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.c" // I just include c file for demo purpose

int main()
{
   printf("Value is %d", globalVariable);
}
```

and there is comile error which says globalVariable already defined in Main.obj

but we know that any global variable or function declared without the static attribute is public and can be accessed by any other module, I didn't define `globalVariable` in main.c, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Use `extern` keyword. And don't include `*.c` files unless you know *exactly* what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `#include "test.c"` includes the contents of `test.c` in the compilation of `main.c`. This causes that compilation to contain the line `int globalVariable = 2020;`. This line **defines** `globalVariable`, which causes memory to be reserved for it.

Presumably you compiled both `main.c` and `test.c`. The compilation of `test.c` **also** contains that line, so it **also** defines `globalVariable`. This is what the linker is complaining about: `globalVariable` is defined twice. It is an error to define one thing two times.

Each object should be defined only once. To use it in another file, you just **declare** it; you do not **define** it. A declaration that is not a definition gives the compiler information about a thing without asking the compiler to reserve space for it.

To do this, you should remove `#include "test.c"` and replace it with the line `extern int globalVariable;`.

The usual way this is done is to put that line in a file called `test.h` and the put the line `#include "test.h"` in both `main.c` and `test.c`. It is included in `main.c` so that the compiler will know about it while compiling `main`, which uses `globalVariable`. It is included in `test.c` as a double-check for correctness: By including `test.h` in `test.c`, both the declaration in `test.h` and the definition in `test.c` will be seen by the compiler, and it will check them for consistency. When a declaration just duplicates the information of a definition, the compiler does not complain. When there is a discrepancy, such as different types, it will complain.

Comment: btw, you mean I should put `int globalVariable;` in `test.h`, and no need to use extern?

Answer (score 0):

first if you define a global variable and include it inside `main.c`. once you compile `main.c`, then compiler would transfer `main.c` into a `main.obj` as well as the included source file `test.c` into another obj file `test.obj` simultaneously. then linker want to put `test.obj` and `main.obj` into one and find `globalVariable` was define twice.
so if you want to avoid this error, just use `extern int globalVariable` in `main.c`, then linker will know it is declaration rather than definition and won't allocate memory space for `globalVariable` in `main.c`.